# Use timer for generating sine waveform in CodeVisionAVR

Tags: c, embedded, waveform

Can anybody help me about [CodeVisionAVR](http://www.hpinfotech.ro/html/cvavr.htm)? I want to write a program for
ATMega16L microcontroller to generate sine waveform using the timer feature 
in CodeVisionAVR, but I don't know how to use OCR with sine wave.

Comment: The use of CodeVision is largely irrelevant; that fact that you are programming in C is more relevant. Timers are are a feature of the hardware not of CodeVision.

Answer (score 1):

Ouptut Compare (OC) timer outputs can only generate square wave.  However they can be used for pulse-width modulation (PWM) where the width of the pulse can be varied; if a PWM waveform output is low-pass filtered, the output will be a voltage proportional to the mark-space ratio of the PWM waveform.  By modifying the pulse width sinusoidally and with suitable filtering you can generate a sine wave output.

So at each timer re-load interrupt you need to modify the pulse-width.  I suggest that you pre-calculate the pulse widths into an array of values and feed them cyclically to the timer on each re-load interrupt.  There are however a number of trade-offs between PWM frequency, pulse-width resolution, analogue filtering and wave-form frequency which would affect the accuracy of the waveform.  You need to balance these variables to suit your requirements with respect to frequency and bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the timer to trigger an interrupt where you write the waveform data out of other GPIO pins (using a resistor ladder as a DAC or similar), you could put the waveform data in a lookup table and step through the table every time an interrupt fires.

Alternatively if you have a suitable PWM output pin, you could use the timer interrupt to de/increment the duty cycle value to give a sine or any other shape wave output. This does require the PWM timer to be going much faster than the required sine wave so you can filter it, but that depends a bit on how accurate you need to be.